# Daily average per working day calculation in power pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I need to create a daily average measure for resolved complaints for each staff member, but am having a difficult time.  I have a table with a list of complaints resolved, a calendar table with a working days indicator, and a staff list.

My output should be a one row table that averages the number of complaints closed per working day for today.  It will update the average each day as the data is refreshed.

I created a measure that counts the number of closed complaints, [Count of Closed Complaints].  I also created a measure that calculates the elapsed number of working days, [Elapsed Working Days] which is `=Day(Today())-TOTALMTD(calculate(count(Calendar[work hours]), Calendar[Work Hours]=0), Calendar[DateKey])`

These two measures appear to work correctly.

However, the daily changing average is driving me nuts.  I have tried the following formulas (as well as many others that use TOTALMTD) and cannot get it to work:

**test average 4** `:=CALCULATE(([Count of Closed Complaints]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(calendar), calendar[Datekey] <= max(calendar[datekey])))/[Elapsed Working Days]`

**test average 3** `:=calculate(([Count of Closed Complaints]/[Elapsed Working Days]), calendar[work hours]>0, DATESMTD(Calendar[DateKey]))`

**test average 2** `:=calculate(AVERAGEA([Count of Closed Complaints]), DATESMTD(Calendar[DateKey]), calendar[work hours]>0)`

Please help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to count closed complaints, not to average them. Use the DISTINCTCOUNT function.

Comment: I need to do both.  I have counted them, no problem.  I display the daily total and the aggregate total on a separate pivot.  My issue is to generate what the staff person's daily average of resolved complaints is each day as the month goes on.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do but it seems as though you are overcomplicating things.

Your average is simply your [Count of Closed Complaints] divided by [Elapsed Working days]. Consider a measure as follows:

```
Closed per day :=
[Count of Closed Complaints] / [Elapsed Working Days]
```

This measure should return the Number of Closed Complaints per working day for all contexts that you want. So if you filter on one staff member for one month you will get the Number of Closed Complaints per day for that staff member for that month.

To make this work you will need to ensure that your Calendar table contains one record per day up to today. That will mean that your average for the current month will always be correct. Your Elapsed Working Days measure can be simplified to

```
Elapsed Working Days :=
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Calendar[work hours] ),
    Calendar[Work Hours] <> 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I initially had these simple formulas, because I thought it WAS simple.  :(    However, these aren't calculating correctly.  The count of complaints resolved IS correct, no question about that.  However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the running total of working days as of today.    For today, June 26, we have had 19 working days--six weekend days and one holiday.  However, when I plug in the[Elapsed Working Day] measure (like the one you mentioned) into a pivot table with the month, it shows 21--the total number of working days in a month.

Comment: I need to get the total number of working days only up until the current day (Today is 19, Saturday and Sunday will remain 19, and Monday will be 20).  I thought the TOTALMTD or DATES MTD would work, but I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: If your Calendar table only goes to today then you will only see 19 working days for this month.

Comment: If your calendar goes beyond today you could add a calculated column to indicate if the date is in the past or future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  My calendar runs until 2025...

I think I may have resolved my problem that gives me the correct answer today.  I'll check on Monday to see if it still works!

I had to change my formula for Elapsed Working Days to: =Day(Today())-TOTALMTD(calculate(count(Calendar[DateKey]), Calendar[Work Hours]=0), Calendar[DateKey])

Then, I created the simple average of [Count of Closed Complaints] divided by [Elapsed Working days] but wrapped it in TOTALMTD.  So, TOTALMTD([Count of Closed Complaints]/[Elapsed Working Days], Calendar[DateKey])

Displaying only today in the pivot table gives me the correct average for today.  As I said earlier, I will see what happens this weekend and on Monday.  I thought I'd solved this problem earlier and then the next day it wasn't.